# Numerical integration of MeijerG function with variables

Tags: numerical-integration, numerics, linear-algebra, special-functions, algebraic-manipulation

I applied the integration, How to solve the function which is mentioned below.
here, 'theta' is the only variable.
q13, q1,q2,p,qi1 are all variables will take value from the loop ranges from 0 to 2, mu is 1.5, L=3, gammak1=1, BI=9, C1=4, Bsd=4, M=2

- a[theta_] =  MeijerG[{{-(q13 + q1 + q2 + (2*mu)+ p - 1), 1 - (q13 + q1 + qi1 + mu + p + (L*mu)), 1 - (q13 + q1 + mu + p)}, {}}, {{0}, {-(q13 + q1 + mu + p)}}, C1 / (BI*gammak1* (Bsd + ((Sin[Pi/M]^2)/(Sin[theta]^2))))]
- Then NIntegrate[a[theta],{theta,0,Pi/2}]

I am not getting the values when I integrate. Even for a day, the simulation is going on.

Comment: You have some variables names together. Also, what are the values for `qi1` and `M`?

Comment: @bbgodfrey - with `M -> 1`, `a[theta]` is independent of `theta`.

Comment: @BobHanlon qi1 = 0 to 2 and M=2

Comment: @bbgodfrey then is it possible to Change this Meijer G function to hypergeometric function or any other form, so that I need to integrate the theta variable?

Comment: Have thought more about this.  Some progress appears possible.

Comment: @bbgodfrey Sir, Can you tell me elaborately?

Comment: Okay Sir. I'll be waiting for you.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Answer (score 3):

The root cause of the difficulties encountered by the OP is that `MeijerG`, as implemented in Mathematica, often is not accurate when evaluated at machine precision.  For instance, with the parameters,

```
params = {p -> 1, q1 -> 1, q2 -> 1, q13 -> 1, qi1 -> 1, mu -> 3/2, 
    L -> 3, gammak1 -> 1, BI -> 9, C1 -> 4, Bsd -> 4, M -> 2};
```

merely plotting the integrand in the Question over a portion of its domain

```
mg = MeijerG[{{-(q13 + q1 + q2 + (2 mu) + p - 1), 
    1 - (q13 + q1 + qi1 + mu + p + (L mu)), 
    1 - (q13 + q1 + mu + p)}, {}}, {{0}, {-(q13 + q1 + mu + p)}}, 
    C1/(BI*gammak1*(Bsd + ((Sin[Pi/M]^2)/(Sin[theta]^2))))] /. params;
LogPlot[mg, {theta, 1/2, Pi/2}, PlotRange -> {{0, Pi/2}, All}, 
   ImageSize -> Large, AxesLabel -> {theta, "mg"}, LabelStyle -> {15, Bold, Black}]
```

is very slow, noisy, and highly inaccurate.

[image]

Not surprisingly, trying to `NIntegrate` this fails.  In fact, obtaining a smooth curve requires a very large `WorkingPrecision`, especially near `theta = 0`.

```
lp = LogPlot[mg, {theta, 1/100, Pi/2}, WorkingPrecision -> 2000, 
    PlotRange -> {{0, Pi/2}, All}, ImageSize -> Large, AxesLabel -> {theta, "mg"}, 
    LabelStyle -> {15, Bold, Black}])
Cases[lp, Line[z_] -> z, Infinity][[1, 2, 1]]
```

[image]

```
(* 0.022446 *)
```

Even with `WorkingPrecision -> 2000`, `Plot` can reach only down to `0.022446`, well above the requested lower bound, `0.01`.  About 70 seconds was required for this computation.
(Note that the first value obtained by `Plot` has been discarded, because it visibly is inaccurate.)  Performing the desired integral requires the integrand to be evaluated all the way to `theta = 0`.  To obtain a reasonable estimate of the function there, `Fit` the very left of the curve above to a biquadratic in `theta`.

```
Rest[First[Cases[lp, Line[z_] -> z, Infinity]]];
fi = Interpolation[%];
val = %%[[1, 1]];
Fit[%%%[[;; 10]], {1, theta^2, theta^4}, theta]
s = Piecewise[{{fi[theta], theta >= val}}, %];
(* 17.877 - 25.3885 theta^2 + 159.428 theta^4 *)
```

`mg` at `theta = 1/100` can be computed from

```
Block[{$MaxExtraPrecision = 100000}, N[mg /. theta -> 10^-2, 6]]
(* 5.79133*10^7 *)
```

in about 70 seconds and agrees well with `Exp[s /. theta -> 1/100]`.  Plotting `Exp[s]` has a credible appearance as well.  The integral now is trivial to perform.

```
NIntegrate[Exp[s], {theta, 0, Pi/2}]
(* 1.62895*10^7 *)
```

In general, the same procedure should work for other parameters.

**Addendum: Faster, simpler code**

Most of the code above can be replaced by

```
fb = Interpolation@Block[{$MaxExtraPrecision = 100000}, 
    Table[{theta, N[mg, 6]}, {theta, 2/100, Ceiling[Pi/2, 1/100], 1/100}]];
Quiet@NIntegrate[fb[theta], {theta, 0, Pi/2}]
(* 1.6289*10^7 *)
```

as before.  This computation requires about 18 seconds, rather than 70 seconds for the previous approach.

Applying the present approach to a different set of parameters, say,

```
SeedRandom[1812];
params = Join[Thread[{p, q1, q2, q13, qi1} -> Rationalize[RandomReal[2, 5], 0]], 
    {mu -> 3/2, L -> 3, gammak1 -> 1, BI -> 9, C1 -> 4, Bsd -> 4, M -> 2}];
```

and defining `mg` and `fb` as before, but with the new `params`, then gives for the integral

```
(* 2.0744*10^6 *)
```

in about 30 seconds.  For completeness, the correspond plot of the integrand is

```
Quiet@LogPlot[fb[theta], {theta, 0, Pi/2}, ImageSize -> Large, 
    AxesLabel -> {theta, "mg"}, LabelStyle -> {15, Bold, Black}]
```

[image]

Comment: I am really satisfied with your answer, Sir. I have one doubt, If I integrate from 2/100 to Pi/2, will I get the approx answer as from 0 to Pi/2?

Comment: @S.Kirubakaran  Integrating over `{2/100, Pi/2}`  is not very accurate.  However, `NIntegrate[fb[theta], {theta, 0, Pi/2}]` is quite accurate, because `fb`, an `InterpolationFunction`, automatically extrapolates to `0` for `NIntegrate` with good accuracy, since `mg` changes slowly there.  See the final plot.

Comment: So, it means that I can directly integrate the mg with fb code. Am I right Sir?

Comment: @S.Kirubakaran  If `mg` is smooth at `theta = 0`, as it appears to be, then you can integrate `mg` with `fb` over all of `{0, Pi/2}`.  As a test, you can extend `Table` to include `1/100`, but doing so can be very slow.     By the way, notice that I applied `Quiet` to `NIntegrate` to turn off warning messages that extrapolation is being used near `theta = 0`.